# Characteristic function of a exponential random variable, problems with complex integral.

Tags: probability, integration, complex-analysis, characteristic-functions

I tried to compute the characteristic function of a random variable, which is exponential distributed with parameter $\lambda$:
\begin{align*}
\varphi(t) &= \mathbb E[e^{itX}] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{itx} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \cdot 1_{[0,\infty)}(x) \, dx
= \lambda \int_0^\infty e^{itx-\lambda x} \, dx
= \lambda \int_0^\infty e^{x(it-\lambda)} \, dx. 
\end{align*}
This is an integral of a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$, $f(x) := e^{x(it-\lambda)}$ over a real segment $[0,\infty)$. In complex analysis we had that in general the integral of such a function is defined as (with $f(x) = u(x)+iv(x)$):
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx = \int_0^\infty u(x) \, dx + i \int_0^\infty v(x) \, dx.
\end{align*}
In this case we have that
\begin{align*}
f(x) = e^{x(it-\lambda)} =  \frac{\cos(tx)}{e^{\lambda x}}+i\frac{\sin(tx)}{e^{\lambda x}},
\end{align*}
but 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(tx)}{e^{\lambda x}} \, dx +i \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(tx)}{e^{\lambda x}} \, dx
\end{align*}
doesn't converge. Thus I don't know how to go on.

Comment: Sure the integrals converge, you have $\lambda > 0$. But you can directly integrate $$\int_0^\infty e^{(it-\lambda)x}\,dx = \frac{e^{(it-\lambda)x}}{it-\lambda}\biggl\lvert_0^\infty = \frac{1}{\lambda-it} = \frac{\lambda+it}{\lambda^2+t^2}.$$

Comment: But why is $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{(it-\lambda)x} = 0$? The $i$ inside there is confusing me.

Comment: You have $\lvert e^{it}\rvert = 1$, so what matters is $e^{-\lambda x}$. We have $\lambda > 0$, so exponential decay.